# Vue: Using a method in a v-for but the getter isn't ready

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a v-for in my template where I use a method to get the name.  Since the v-for is hit immediately on page load and runs through the method for each index, the `pages` I grab in the method are usually undefined the first few loops ( `let pages = this.$store.getters['section2/getPages']` ).  Is there a better way to handle this?

template:

```html
<div class="target-box-child" v-for="(target,index) in this.$store.getters['liveDashboard/getDesiredTargets']" :key="index">
   <div>{{ getGroupOrPageName(target) }}</div>
</div>
```

```js
methods: {
  getGroupOrPageName: function(target) {
    if (target.type == "page") {
      let pages = this.$store.getters['section2/getPages'];
      if (!pages || pages.length == 0) {
        return;
      }
      pages.filter(page => {
        return page.id == target.id;
      })
      return "FB Page: " + pages[0].name;
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As always, using methods to render parts of your template is a [bad idea](https://medium.com/notonlycss/the-difference-between-computed-and-methods-in-vue-js-9cb05c59ed98).

Instead, I would create a computed property to produce an array of pages that is reactive to both your `liveDashboard/getDesiredTargets` and `section2/getPages` getters.

You can also use the `mapGetters` helper to reduce some of those long getters names

```html
<div class="target-box-child" v-for="targetPage in targetPages" :key="targetPage.id">
   <div>FB Page: {{ targetPage.name }}</div>
</div>
```

```js
import { mapGetters } from "vuex"

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("liveDashboard", {
      targets: "getDesiredTargets" // alias "liveDashboard/getDesiredTargets" as "this.targets"
    }),
    ...mapGetters("section2", {
      pages: "getPages" // alias "section2/getPages" as "this.pages"
    }),
    targetPages: ({ targets, pages }) => {
      // create a map for easy location
      const pagesById = (pages ?? []).reduce((map, page) =>
        map.set(page.id, page), new Map())
    
      // find the "page" target IDs
      const targetIds = targets.filter(({ type }) => type === "page")
        .map(({ id }) => id)

      // now build up an array from the target IDs
      return targetIds.reduce((arr, id) => {
        if (pagesById.has(id)) {
          arr.push(pagesById.get(id))
        }
        return arr
      }, [])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just curious: why is it so often said that using methods in template is a bad idea tho? I thought as long as it doesn't have any side effects or perform asynchronous operations, it should be pretty okay to use them.

Comment: @Terry https://medium.com/notonlycss/the-difference-between-computed-and-methods-in-vue-js-9cb05c59ed98. Also see this part of the official guide https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a computed property for your getter. The best practice is to use [mapGetters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper) for that in order to reduce boilerplate code.

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

 computed: {
...mapGetters('liveDashboard', ['getDesiredTargets']),
}
```

Then in your template add v-if condition before your v-for loop ([Here is why](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/index.html#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential)).

```
<template v-if="getDesiredTargets">
<div class="target-box-child" v-for="(target,index) in getDesiredTargets" :key="index">
   <div>{{ getGroupOrPageName(target) }}</div>
</div>
<template />
```